# i is undefined [bootstrap 4]

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4.1.x through CDNs

The issue is that half the time when I'm loading a page, JavaScript throws an error:

> TypeError: i is undefined
>
> bootstrap.min.js:6:2691

sometimes it comes from bootstrap's utils.js

I'm using JavaScript to generate the HTML parts of the page with:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = myString;
```

This is the actual string:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <a class="modal-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#educ">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <img class="card-img" src="/content/images/logo.png"> Logo</h5>
        <div class="card-text">
          some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="educ">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header py-2">
        <h4 class="modal-title">modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      </div>

      <!--modal body-->
      <div class="modal-body d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <h4>title</h4>

        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
          <img src="#" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-modal" alt="Paris">
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn custombtn-red" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#esm">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> cours</button>
        <div id="esm" class="collapse">
          <p class="titre2">collapse text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn custombtn-red" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm new to JavaScript, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I would gladly use any help to find where this error comes from.

edit: the CDNs i'm using

```
<link async rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link async href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">

<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery did you add to your file?

Comment: @Phiter, jQuery? Doesn't seem like there is any jQuery involved here?!

Comment: Bootstrap uses jQuery, and if he uses an older version it could result in some problems.

Comment: 3.3.1  I'll update the question with the cdn links

Comment: Are you using DataTables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767889/datatables-typeerror-i-is-undefined

Comment: Try to use defer instead of async and load Jquery before Bootstrap (invert line 5 and line 2)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

async attribute do not guarantee loading resolution order (see [When to use async vs defer when loading scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443870/when-to-use-async-vs-defer-when-loading-scripts)). If Jquery doesn't win the loading race, Boostrap will defect.

You better use defer instead of async and load Jquery first :

```
<script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script defer src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's working fine now, also thank you for the informative link, didn't knew about the defer keyword

Comment: U're welcome. By the way, stylesheets are already loaded asynchronously. The attribute async have no meaning in a <link> tag. And if you're wondering where to put your script calls, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337112/defer-js-loading-insert-to-head-or-body